# Javascript onClick() Requiring Multiple Clicks

Tags: javascript, navigation, dropdown

Good Morning --

I have read through multiple posts with a very similar issue to mine but I still am unable to find a feasible solution. My sideNav is requiring an initial click before it begins working on every click and my dropdown boxes are requiring me double click before anything happens. I have been attempting to fix this for a few days now and was hoping someone here could help.

I have attached my code below. Thanks everyone for taking the time out of your day to help.

https://codepen.io/Bryant_Mitchell/pen/KKPbQLy

```
    function sideBar() {
      var sideBar = document.getElementById("sideBar"),
      main = document.getElementById("main");
      sideBar.style.width = sideBar.style.width === "250px" ? '0' : '250px';
      main.style.marginLeft = main.style.marginLeft === "250px" ? '0' :  '250px';
    }

function collapseButton() {
  var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown");
  var i;

      for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
        coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
          this.classList.toggle("active");
          var content = this.nextElementSibling;
          if (content.style.maxHeight){
            content.style.maxHeight = null;
          } else {
            content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
          }
        });
      }
  }
```

P.S. one additional issues I am having but it does not take any priority, when hiding my sideNav it tends to push the content down and is unsightly. I know I can increase the size of the navigation and it will fix this issue but I was wandering if there was any other way to fix it. Again, this isn't really a priority for me but figured I would ask here instead of making another post later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  function sideBar() {

  var sideBar = document.getElementById("sideBar"),
  main = document.getElementById("main");
  sideBar.style.width = sideBar.style.width === "250px" ? '0' : '250px';
  main.style.marginLeft = main.style.marginLeft === "250px" ? '0' : '250px';

  }



function collapseButton() {

  var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      var content = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (content.style.maxHeight) {
        content.style.maxHeight = null;
      } else {
        content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
      }
    });
  }



 }

  addEventListener("load", collapseButton);
```

addevntlistner can call your collapseButton function like above . 
But remember to remove the onclick statement in your html file as shown below.

```
<button type="button" class="dropdown" >Projects</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the onclick Attribute of the dropdown Element in your HTML an add following Line at the end of your code:

```
addEventListener("load", collapseButton);
```

Comment: That still forces me to double click the dropdown for it to activate.

Comment: Did you removed the "onclick=collapseButton()" Attribute?

Comment: I did remove it. Seems it still isn't fixing the issue, unfortunately.

Comment: This should fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because the sidebar doesn't have an initial `style.width` value. You're querying an inline style value, not the [computed style value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

This code:

```
sideBar.style.width === "250px" ? '0' : '250px';
```

is the issue. On first run, your sidebar doesn't have an inline width value. When you click it the first time, *then* it gets an inline style value of 250px. You can skip this by calculating the *computed* width, not the inline width:

```
function sideBar() {
  var sideBar = document.getElementById("sideBar");
  var main = document.getElementById("main");
  var sidebarWidth = getComputedStyle(sideBar).width;
  var mainMargin = getComputedStyle(main).marginLeft;
  sideBar.style.width = sidebarWidth === "250px" ? '0' : '250px';
  main.style.marginLeft = mainMargin  === "250px" ? '0' :  '250px';
}
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/darren1337/pen/bGbzxzZ)

You can do something similar for your dropdown.

Comment: +1 Thank you for not only the solution but an explanation. One question though. Is there a reason that this now does not shift the "main" container to the left and the right?

Comment: Sorry about that, I was targeting the width of the main element, not the left margin. Try it now.

Comment: Much appreciated! That is one of two issues fixed thanks to you. I very much appreciate it! I will look at implementing a similar solution on my dropdown!

Comment: Done and done! I assume I am just getting the ComputedStyle for maxHeight on this one, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right. If you ever need to find the full name of the property you're looking for, try running `getComputedStyle(document.body)` in the console for a full list.